# CSS absolute without scrolling

Tags: css

**Update:**
Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/d4wng3g2/1/

The goal (in the fiddle) is to allow the red box to remain on top of the scrollable area but when you move the horizontal scrollbar, I would like the red box to remain in its container (i.e under icon)

---

Here's the problem I'm facing:

If I have the following: (I know style shouldn't be inline - this is just to explain my purpose here)

```
<div style='position: relative' class='parent-box'>
  <div style='position: absolute' class='image-select-container'>
    <div style='position: absolute' class='image-selected-container-inner>
      <ul style='position: absolute' class='image-select'></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>v
```

[image]

In order to allow the box to go over the parent, I made the parent absolute too

```
<div style='position: absolute' class='parent-box'>
```

[image]

which fixes my zindex problem but causes me the following problem when scrolling horizontally:

The div is acting as fixed - which is partially what I want to achieve overlay but I do not want it to scroll.

[image]

Comment: How ul inside div. Please post proper code here and if possible create snippet/Fiddle.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for the 'overflow' css property to be set to none:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: I do not want the overflow to be hidden because I have a table and I want it to show on smaller devices. So basically, the second image is what I want to achieve but I don't want it to be "fixed" when scrolling horizontally.

Comment: @ketan The apple in the last image moves too (even if I had not list). I only added the <ul> here so you can relate to the images =)

Comment: @Abdo could you share fiddle? Try using overflow-y visible?

Comment: Should I start a bounty?

Answer (score 0):

As the parent box is absolute, it will not move when scrolling. You can add yet another parent container with position relative and display: block; which will move when you scroll and all the absolute divs within will move with it.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the fiddle?